# In EMV application setting TVR is L2 level task or L3 level?

Tags: payment-processing, emv, mastercard

In EMV card processing terminal application, setting TVR bits is a task for L2 kernel or it has to be handled by L3 application?
I'm not appropriate documentation for this. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Level2 Task. The Specs on emvco.com describe this in detail.

Comment: Which document it is described, can you please give reference point number?

Comment: This depends what is your Level2 Kernel. Contacted or Contactless? MasterCard/Visa/AMEX something else. Just grep through your PDFs for TVR